# Secure data transfer in swift

Tags: ios, security, swift, http, ssl

I'm developing an iOS app with Swift that sends user data to a server through HTTP (using POST method). I'm wondering what could I do to encrypt this data. Installing an SSL certificate in the server should do the trick? Or is there anything else I should do?

And the same for the data sent from the server to the device. Is SSL enough?

And another thing I don't really understand: should I encode the text with base64 before sending it to the server? Why is base64 encoding beeing used if it can be decoded by anyone?

I don't know if these are basic questions. If so, I apologize for that!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: installing the cert is one part, but you'd also have to start using `https` urls. and yes, ssl will prevent most forms of sniffing/data theft, but it's not a 100% secure solution. ssl has had MANY protocol level holes punched into it, and the whole certificate issuance business is a total gong show (there's better language to describe it, but it's not appropriate for this site).

Answer (score 1):

Use https (SSL/TLS), it encrypts the connection. If you are concerned about MITM attacks pin the certificate, there are many sources for how to do this and AFNetworking supports pinning.

Make sure you only allow https connections and do not allow legacy encryption such as RC4.